# SQL Case ELSE in the Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio) I'm attempting to use a Case statement in my where clause in order to filter my results.
What I'd like to have happen is IF there is a CatID that ends in 6 I want to see that entry only otherwise I'd like to see what's left. In this case I want to see only the W6 and not the WW CatID.

I haven't been able to find the proper syntax for using the Else in my situation and I've tried to use different criteria in order to exclude WW when W6 is shown but it just shows both.

Any help on how to use the proper syntax with the ELSE in my case statement would be greatly appreciated.

Current Results:

```
PackNuM| Description            |CatID  |Page   |Prefix_Quarter |Current Retail |Current High Retail |Current DRC |Season_id |year |Brand_Offer
6790785| AMY CNVRTBLE BLT BAG   |W6     |910    |NULL           |               |                    |            |F21       |2021 |W6
6790785| AMY CNVRTBLE BLT BAG   |WW     |910    |Q3             |               |                    |            |F21       |2021 |W6
```

Current Code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
a.PackNum,
a.Description,
a.CatID,
a.Page,
c.prefix_Quarter,
'' AS [Current Retail],
'' AS [Current High Retail],     
'' as [Current DRC],
b.Season_id,
a.year,
b.Brand_Offer 

FROM PIC704Current a FULL JOIN #CatCov b ON (a.CatID = b.Offer) and (a.Year = b.MailYear) 
FULL JOIN CatalogInfo c on (a.CatID = c.Catalog) and (a.Year = c.MailYear)
JOIN

(SELECT DISTINCT PackNum, CatID, Year, b.InternetActiveDate
FROM PIC704Current a JOIN #catcov b ON (a.CatID = b.Offer) and (a.Year = b.MailYear)
WHERE
(CASE WHEN a.PackNum = '6790785' then 1
      WHEN b.Offer_Type In('Web-Main', 'Web-Only', 'Web-Mega') then 1

      ELSE 0 END) = 1

and b.Offer_Type In('Web-Main', 'Web-Only', 'Web-Mega') 
and (cast(b.InternetActiveDate as datetime) = (select Max(cast(InternetActiveDate as datetime)) from #catcov c2 where CONCAT(b.Offer,b.MailYear) = Concat(c2.Offer,c2.MailYear)) or b.InternetActiveDate is null) 
)q

ON (a.PackNum = q.PackNum) and (a.Year = q.Year) and (a.CatID = q.CatID)

WHERE 
(Case When b.Offer_Type In('Web-Main', 'Web-Only', 'Web-Mega') and b.price_type = 'Full' and b.Price_Type <> 'Sale' then 1 
      When b.Offer_Type In('Web-Main', 'Web-Only', 'Web-Mega') and b.price_type = 'Sale' and b.Price_Type <> 'FULL' then 1 
      ELSE 0 END) = 1

and a.PackNum = '6790785'
and a.Page not in('851')
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). Also, what you have is a `CASE` **expression**, *not* a `Case` Statement.

Comment: add another filter as `and right(a.catid,1)=6`

Comment: why use Case at all?  `WHERE 
((b.Offer_Type In('Web-Main', 'Web-Only', 'Web-Mega') and b.price_type = 'Full' and b.Price_Type <> 'Sale') OR (b.Offer_Type In('Web-Main', 'Web-Only', 'Web-Mega') and b.price_type = 'Sale' and b.Price_Type <> 'FULL')) and ....`
`

Comment: @larnu yes I know I have "Bad habits" but I'm still learning SQL and right now I'm doing it the way I understand.

Comment: If you are learning SQL, then all the more reason to use meaningful and consistent aliases, @Deke ; it'll make things like easier for you.

Comment: @KenOn10 because then I still just get the same result above. I want only the CatID that has a 6 if there is one otherwise I want whatever else is there. I wish this was as simple as an IF Then Else.

Comment: It is obvious you struggle for many reasons. The use of multiple DISTINCT operators, multiple references to the same tables, multiple uses of the same literals, a lack of formatting that hinders understanding, etc. If you were to focus on improving the query (which is highly likely to simplify it as well), then a solution to your actual issue might be easier to achieve. Your FULL JOINS are logically converted to (plain ole) outer joins due to the last inner join and the WHERE clause. <cont>

Comment: Unfortunately your schema is not obvious to me (and likely others). You have a significant logic problem trying to include rows with a certain value "or else" and it is difficult to know how to structure that without knowing what the "key values" are for a given row within the resultset. So in the end - it is very difficult to help without significantly more information. My best suggestion is to rewrite the query as a starting point.

Comment: Maybe a better analogy would be if your neighbor is building his house and getting to pour the foundation. Your neighbor has set up his concrete forms perfectly. But then you see him dumping bags of dry cement into the forms and then using his hose to pour water. Then taking a big stick and mixing it. Do you offer a better way of mixing concrete or do you simply go over and help him stir? The people here don't want to work so hard by stirring and instead are suggesting a better way of mixing so the result is better and requires less effort. You get decide how the help is received.

Comment: To help us help you, you should break this down into the simplest problem you can, we have no idea why you are doing all these FULL JOINS and JOINS on SELECTS. It is very rare to see FULL JOINS. Give us the TABLE definitions, some sample data and a minimally reproducible problem.

Comment: I’m self taught and still learning. Tell me from the link I was provided exactly how I learn to code like an expert? I’m sorry to have wasted everyone’s time. I’m sorry I bothered asking a question. All I was asking for was if there was syntax to do what I wanted and if so an example would have been nice.

Comment: @SteveFord The Joins are because there are several different tables I need data from that all line up. For example Pic704Current has all my PackNumbers, and CatID's which joins with Table CatCov's Offers and Internet active dates which I need to pull the correct info and columns. I have the inner query pulling the most recent Packnumber+CatID and the outer query to compare a specific pack in the inner query. (So that if pack 123456 is pulled by the inner query I can pull that data for the outer query)

Comment: You do realise that using a FULL OUTER JOIN means that you will return rows when there is a row in CatalogInfo even if there is no matching row in Pic704Current, so that your return row would be NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, CatalogInfo.PrefixQuarter etc. I'm sure that this is not what you want and vice versa. If you want rows from Pic704Current even if there is no matching info in CatalogInfo you need a LEFT OUTER JOIN, if you only want rows where there is a match you need an INNER JOIN. OUTER & INNER don't refer to where the statement appears!

Comment: Thanks Steve, I do realize what the FULL JOIN is pulling in all data from both tables. That's actually what I want. The W6 only appears in the Pic704Current.CatiD and won't show in the CatCov.Offer so I want both options because sometimes there won't be a W6 and when that's the case I just want what is left. I'll play around with the Joins some more. I've been trying to find other alternatives, but honestly I'm beaten down by this thread. I'll look at my code again tomorrow.

Comment: @Deke I would honestly try to simplify this as I have over 20 years experience and I struggle to understand what your query is doing, so I would suggest that it is likely to be unmaintable (IMHO sorry). In terms of getting help on SO you should present the simplest question that shows your issue, so if I was asking for help I would show code to create 3 simple tables, insert rows into these and then a simple query which you believe needs a CASE statement and see what answers you get.. Sounds like an EXISTS clause might help you. Oh and I can't see where you check for W6 anywhere.

Comment: @SteveFord Thanks for the suggestion. I've been looking up the uses for EXISTS and IN. The most basic way I can try to explain what I'm trying to do is just a simple If this exists then give me this, else give me whatever else is there. Hopefully that makes sense? I'm still working through things I've been reading a bunch. But I'm self taught and that means a lot of trial and error. Doing my best with what I have. I appreciate the reply and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have greatly simplified your queries to show the use of `NOT EXISTS` to answer your question:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b9092/3)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Results
(
  PAckNum INT,
  Description Varchar(50),
  CatID VARCHAR(10),
  Page Int,
  Prefix_Quarter VARCHAR(2),
  Season_id varchar(3),
  [year] int,
  Brand_Offer VARCHAR(10)
  );
  
  INSERT INTO Results 
  VALUES 
  (6790785, 'AMY CNVRTBLE BLT BAG', 'W6', 910, NULL, 'F21', 2021, 'W6'),
  (6790785, 'AMY CNVRTBLE BLT BAG', 'WW', 910, 'Q3', 'F21', 2021, 'W6'),
  (6790786, 'AMY CNVRTBLE BLT BAG', 'WW', 910, NULL, 'F21', 2021, 'W6'),
  (6790786, 'AMY CNVRTBLE BLT BAG', 'WW', 910, 'Q3', 'F21', 2021, 'W6')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM Results R1
WHERE R1.CATID = 'W6'
OR (NOT EXISTS 
             (SELECT NULL 
              FROM Results 
              WHERE R1.PackNum = PackNum AND CatId = 'W6') AND
              R1.CatId <> 'W6')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b9092/3/0)**:

```
| PAckNum |          Description | CatID | Page | Prefix_Quarter | Season_id | year | Brand_Offer |
|---------|----------------------|-------|------|----------------|-----------|------|-------------|
| 6790785 | AMY CNVRTBLE BLT BAG |    W6 |  910 |         (null) |       F21 | 2021 |          W6 |
| 6790786 | AMY CNVRTBLE BLT BAG |    WW |  910 |         (null) |       F21 | 2021 |          W6 |
| 6790786 | AMY CNVRTBLE BLT BAG |    WW |  910 |             Q3 |       F21 | 2021 |          W6 |
```

Comment: This did the trick! I'm still working on trying to clean up my code based on all the examples I've gotten but this really helped! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Deke glad it helped you, if you need help in the future, please think about how you can simplify your questions to the nub of the problem, so that it gives the other members on here the best possible chance to help.

Answer (score 0):

let's take this subquery to understand how can we do it

```
SELECT DISTINCT PackNum, CatID, Year, b.InternetActiveDate
FROM PIC704Current a JOIN #catcov b ON (a.CatID = b.Offer) and (a.Year = b.MailYear)
WHERE
(CASE WHEN a.PackNum = '6790785' then 1
      WHEN b.Offer_Type In('Web-Main', 'Web-Only', 'Web-Mega') then 1
      ELSE 0 END
```

Here you are using the `WHERE` clause to filter records in which either `a.PackNum = '6790785'` or `b.Offer_Type In('Web-Main', 'Web-Only', 'Web-Mega')`

1. This can also be achieved by

> ```
>     SELECT 
>         DISTINCT PackNum, CatID, Year, b.InternetActiveDate
>     FROM PIC704Current a JOIN #catcov b 
>     ON (a.CatID = b.Offer) and (a.Year = b.MailYear)
>     WHERE 
>         a.PackNum = '6790785' 
>         OR b.Offer_Type In('Web-Main', 'Web-Only', 'Web-Mega')
> ```

As @KenOn10 suggested and if it doesn't return your desired result then it won't return your desired result by using case either. So you need to check your condition.

If you insist on going with case/switch, here is how you can do it

```
declare @WhereCheck int;
set @WhereCheck = 1;
SELECT DISTINCT PackNum, CatID, Year, b.InternetActiveDate
FROM PIC704Current a JOIN #catcov b ON (a.CatID = b.Offer) and (a.Year = b.MailYear)
WHERE @WhereCheck =
      CASE 
         WHEN a.PackNum = '6790785' then 1
         WHEN b.Offer_Type In('Web-Main', 'Web-Only', 'Web-Mega') then 1
         ELSE 0 
      END
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm trying to understand the addition of Declare. It appears to be a defining WhereCheck as an integer and then setting it 1 (on?) but I'm a little confused on it's use in the Where. Since werecheck = 1 then show only if the case items =1? but I don't see how this allows me to exclude certain results if another result is present. I really appreciate the example though and I will definitely use this to work on cleaning up my code after I figure it all out. Looking up Declare now to see what I can learn.

Comment: There are certain syntax that we have to follow. where clause expects a distinct value on the right side of '=' to compare with. You can try it without the variable, it might work. like this `WHERE 1 = CASE`. But I am not sure `Declare` only work as a command to declare a variable. `DECLARE @variableName dataType`